# HTTPClient Alternative?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I Need an alternative for `HTTPClient` class in `Android`.
Since `HTTPClient` was removed in `SDK23`. 
When I use `HTTPURLCONNECTION` class, it won't do the appropriate job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Google Volley SDK.  It is way faster than using the standard Android HTTP client.